# Anti-diagonal matrix with alternating signs

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I am having trouble modifying the code below so that the sign of the `x` alternate. That is, from the upper right corner it should read `{-x, x, -x, x, ...}`. Any suggestions?

```
n = 5
SparseArray[
  Band[{1, n}, Automatic, {1, -1}] -> x, {n, n}
] // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this instead:

```
n = 5;
m = Reverse[DiagonalMatrix@SparseArray@Array[x (-1)^# &, n], 2];
 
(** Sparse array:
{{0, 0, 0, 0, -x},
 {0, 0,  0, x, 0},
 {0, 0, -x, 0, 0},
 {0,  x, 0, 0, 0},
 {-x, 0, 0, 0, 0}} **)
```

Comment: You could also remove `SparseArray`, and use `DiagonalMatrix[..., TargetStructure -> "Sparse"]` if you wanted to.

Answer (score 7):

```
n = 5;

MatrixForm @ Reverse @ SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}, {n, n}] :> {-x, x}, {n, n}]

MatrixForm @ Quiet @ 
  SparseArray[Band[{1, n}, {n, 1}, {1, -1}] -> {-x, x}, {n, n}]


MatrixForm @ SparseArray[Band[{1, n}, Automatic, {1, -1}] -> 
   Table[(-1)^i  x, {i, n}], {n, n}]

MatrixForm @ 
 SparseArray[({i_, j_} /; j == n - i + 1) :> (-1)^i  x , {n, n}]
```

All of the above give

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Using `Array` and `If`:

```
With[{n = 5}, Array[If[#1 + #2 == n + 1, x*(-1)^#1, 0] &, {n, n}]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Or using `FoldList`:

```
f[i_, j_, n_] := If[i + j == n + 1, x*(-1)^i, 0]

With[{n = 5}, Last@FoldList[Function[{p}, Append[p, 
     Array[f[Length[p] + 1, #, n] &, n]]], {}, Range[n]]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just to participate:

```
n = 5;
SparseArray[{i_, j_} :> (-1)^i x /; j == n + 1 - i, {n,n}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]